# how to pass local file instead of url to redocstandalone specurl

Tags: javascript, api, yaml, documentation, redoc

I am trying to use redocstandalone component to host my openApi yaml file. The problem is that redocstandalone accepts a specUrl option which is accepting a url for the yaml file to be hosted. When I pass in the url of the hosted yaml file it works correctly but when I pass a path for a local file it does not work. is there a way I can use a local path with redocstandalone instead of using a url for a hosted file?

Answer (score 0):

Local files do not work due to same-origin policy restrictions:

https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/issues/149